# MySQL - How do I automatically manage updates on multiple databases?

Tags: php, mysql, database

For my MySQL application I am required to have every client on the their own database i.e. the database is NOT multi-tenant. Therefore, I have many copies of the same MySQL database schema on multiple servers.

How do I automate the propagation of SQL DDL, such as ALTER TABLE, CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE, CREATE INDEX etc. across multiple databases on multiple servers?

I may have more than 300 databases in the next few months on 4 or more servers.

Comment: Write a script that runs your SQL upgrades on every databases on every server.

Comment: create a table with the databases in question (server, dbname). Pick the programming language of your choice (may I suggest Python, Java, c#). Loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can automate your workflow (If the manipulation is always the same) with a cronjob and the mysql client:

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE < /home/aFileWithSQLStatements.txt
```

Is it that what you are looking for?

Comment: I was hoping to find a tool that would automate the process. I agree with you that I can write scripts as you mention or in php. I think php would be a little better so I can code what notifications to issue on errors.

Comment: use php or bash what ever fits your needs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Time to graduate to using a migration library.  Migrations will allow you to apply or rollback changes on a given schema (ideal for management especially if you have many copies of the same db schema).  Think of it as version control for your DB schema.

An individual migration runs SQL needed to apply a given change or revert it.  Some migration systems are just raw SQL files, other use an abstraction model to define the migration, then auto generates the SQL (often able to work across different DB technologies like MySQL, oracle, or sqlite).

Since you're using PHP, I like `phinx` https://phinx.org/.  You write your migrations then can run them against many different DB's by just updating the current envirment variables:

```
   ...some migrations written, now apply them...

   $> export PHINX_DBHOST=127.0.0.1
   $> export PHINX_DBUSER=root 
   $> export PHINX_DBPASS=password

   $> export PHINX_DBNAME=db1
   $> phinx migrate

   $> export PHINX_DBNAME=db2
   $> phinx migrate

   $> export PHINX_DBNAME=db3
   $> phinx migrate

   .... etc....
```

This will keep all the DB's with all the same modifications in sync.  Phinx also keeps track of which migrations have been run against a given DB, so you can determine easily by just looking in the migration table (tracks migrations run) to learn the current state of the schema for a particular DB without having to inspect individual tables for specific changes.

Then to automate, you can just write a script or have a job that applies the migration on each DB--they don't even need to be on the same machine!